# Putting a UIView between UINavigationBar and status bar in order to show custom ads

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

So I'm struggling with a task I assumed would be easy. I'd like to place a UIView to show ads between the UINavigationBar and the top of the window like thus:

[image]

It seems like I have two options:

**Option (1)**

Somehow programmatically push the UINavigationBar downwards and then programmatically insert the UIView above the navigation bar and flush with the bottom of the status bar:

[image]

**Option (2)**

Dragging a "custom" UINavigationBar onto the main view then placing a UIView above the custom navigation bar:

[image]

In both options, I'm using a navigation controller for push transitions. In the second option, though, I hide the inbuilt navigation bar since I'm using the custom one.

I've tried both options hitting a brick wall in each. I may edit this question later to go into detail where I've got stuck.............

...........but this should be straightforward!

What's the stock-standard way of putting a UIView between the navigation bar and the status bar? Or, in other words, how do apps that show custom ads (non-iAds) up the top of the app actually show them?

I fear/hope that the solution is blindingly obvious and I'm just not choosing my google search terms wisely.

Comment: how did you solve this finally, i am into a similar situation.